# Smallest field containing $\mathbb{Q}$ and closed under square root

Tags: field-theory, geometric-construction

I'm following Isaacs' Algebra and I need to prove that the field $K$ of constructible numbers is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ such that is closed under taking square root.

I already know that $K$ is in fact a field and that if $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\alpha^2\in K$ then $\alpha\in K$ but I don't know how to prove that is the smallest subfield that verifies that property.

Comment: One shows, by induction on the length of a construction, that all numbers obtained at stage $n$ are in the field.

Comment: I don't understand why that proves that the field is minimal

Comment: You are right, nothing is needed to prove it is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ closed under square root. For let $F$ be any subfield of $\mathbb{C}$, and let $w\in K$. From the construction of $w$, we have that $w\in F$.